# Scala: Detecting a Straight in a 5-card Poker hand using pattern matching

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, idioms

For those who don't know what a 5-card Poker Straight is: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_poker_hands#Straight

I'm writing a small Poker simulator in Scala to help me learn the language, and I've created a *Hand* class with 5 ordered *Cards* in it. Each *Card* has a *Rank* and *Suit*, both defined as *Enumerations*. The *Hand* class has methods to evaluate the hand rank, and one of them checks whether the hand contains a Straight (we can ignore Straight Flushes for the moment). I know there are a few nice algorithms for determining a Straight, but I wanted to see whether I could design something with Scala's pattern matching, so I came up with the following:

```
def isStraight() = {
  def matchesStraight(ranks: List[Rank.Value]): Boolean = ranks match {
    case head :: Nil  => true
    case head :: tail if (Rank(head.id + 1) == tail.head) => matchesStraight(tail)
    case _ => false
  }

  matchesStraight(cards.map(_.rank).toList)
}
```

That works fine and is fairly readable, but I was wondering if there is any way to get rid of that *if*. I'd imagine something like the following, though I can't get it to work:

```
private def isStraight() = {
  def matchesStraight(ranks: List[Rank.Value]): Boolean = ranks match {
    case head :: Nil  => true
    case head :: next(head.id + 1) :: tail => matchesStraight(next :: tail)
    case _ => false
  }

  matchesStraight(cards.map(_.rank).toList)
}
```

Any ideas? Also, as a side question, what is the general opinion on the inner *matchesStraight* definition? Should this rather be private or perhaps done in a different way?

Comment: You can define your own extractor, which would look like whatever you desire and also accomplish whatever you need.

Comment: @agilesteel I considered that, but (1) I haven't found a way to still refer to that matched value for the recursive call and (2) I believe I'll need to create an extractor for the '+' as well then?

Comment: If enumerations defined `unapply` method automatically, you could write this as `case head :: (next @ Rank(nextRank)) :: tail if nextRank == head.id + 1`, but they don't.

Comment: Thanks Alexey, that solves issue (1) at least ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't pass information to an extractor, and you can't use information from one value returned in another, except on the `if` statement -- which is there to cover all these cases.

What you can do is create your own extractors to test these things, but it won't gain you much if there isn't any reuse.

For example:

```
class SeqExtractor[A, B](f: A => B) {
  def unapplySeq(s: Seq[A]): Option[Seq[A]] =
    if (s map f sliding 2 forall { case Seq(a, b) => a == b  } ) Some(s)
    else None
}

val Straight = new SeqExtractor((_: Card).rank)
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
listOfCards match {
    case Straight(cards) => true
    case _ => false
}
```

But, of course, all that you really want is that `if` statement in `SeqExtractor`. So, don't get too much in love with a solution, as you may miss simpler ways of doing stuff.

Comment: Thanks Daniel; I underestimated the power of extractors. I get what you're saying about going for the simpler solution, but currently I'm just trying to understand the possible options available.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like:

```
val ids = ranks.map(_.id)
ids.max - ids.min == 4 && ids.distinct.length == 5
```

Handling aces correctly requires a bit of work, though.

**Update:** Here's a much better solution:

```
(ids zip ids.tail).forall{case (p,q) => q%13==(p+1)%13}
```

The `% 13` in the comparison handles aces being both rank 1 and rank 14.

Comment: Nice.  Much more functional and at least this has a bit of pattern matching in it :)  I believe the OP could solve this using any of the methods given here, but he originally wanted a _pattern matching_ solution (without the `if`)... and nothing so far has really done it for him.  Now, I don't really have a good one either, but this solution is concise and pretty.

Comment: I like your solution a lot, it is probably the "best" available. But like Derek mentioned, this question is more about helping me understand pattern matching than coming up with the best solution. If I can't find anything else that solves my specific request, I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like:

`def isStraight(cards:List[Card]) = (cards zip cards.tail) forall { case (c1,c2) => c1.rank+1 == c2.rank}`

`val cards = List(Card(1),Card(2),Card(3),Card(4))`

```
scala> isStraight(cards)
res2: Boolean = true
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a completely different approache, but it does use pattern matching. It produces warnings in the match clause which seem to indicate that it shouldn't work. But it actually produces the correct results:

```
Straight !!! 34567
Straight !!! 34567
Sorry no straight this time
```

I ignored the Suites for now and I also ignored the possibility of an ace under a 2.

```
abstract class Rank {
    def value : Int
}
case class Next[A <: Rank](a : A) extends Rank {
    def value = a.value + 1
}
case class Two() extends Rank {
    def value = 2
}

class Hand(a : Rank, b : Rank, c : Rank, d : Rank, e : Rank) {
    val cards = List(a, b, c, d, e).sortWith(_.value < _.value)
}

object Hand{
    def unapply(h : Hand) : Option[(Rank, Rank, Rank, Rank, Rank)] = Some((h.cards(0), h.cards(1), h.cards(2), h.cards(3), h.cards(4)))
}

object Poker {

    val two = Two()
    val three = Next(two)
    val four = Next(three)
    val five = Next(four)
    val six = Next(five)
    val seven = Next(six)
    val eight = Next(seven)
    val nine = Next(eight)
    val ten = Next(nine)
    val jack = Next(ten)
    val queen = Next(jack)
    val king = Next(queen)
    val ace = Next(king)

    def main(args : Array[String]) {
        val simpleStraight = new Hand(three, four, five, six, seven)
        val unsortedStraight = new Hand(four, seven, three, six, five)
        val notStraight = new Hand (two, two, five, five, ace)

        printIfStraight(simpleStraight)
        printIfStraight(unsortedStraight)
        printIfStraight(notStraight)
    }

    def printIfStraight[A](h : Hand) {

        h match  {
            case  Hand(a: A , b : Next[A], c : Next[Next[A]], d : Next[Next[Next[A]]], e : Next[Next[Next[Next[A]]]]) => println("Straight !!! " + a.value + b.value + c.value + d.value + e.value)
            case Hand(a,b,c,d,e)  => println("Sorry no straight this time")
        }
    }
}
```

If you are interested in more stuff like this google 'church numerals scala type system'

Comment: Please note that your encoding is not a Church encoding of numbers - your numbers aren't functions of zero and the successor function, thus you could not define e.g. addition directly on your numbers. Thus that's not a real Church encoding system.

Comment: You get a warning about incomplete cases because (according to its type) unapply might fail. To fix this warning, you might define Hand as a case class, and replace calls to its constructor with calls to a factory method which performs the sorting of arguments: thus the compiler will know that matching `Hand(a, b, c, d, e)` is never going to fail.
Here, however, you might as well replace the default case with `case _ => println("Sorry no straight this time")`, since the params are not used.

Comment: A nice solution, but can't handle the ambiguity of aces.

Comment: @Blaisorblade: You are correct, this aren't church numerals, but Rank is inspired by church numerals.

Comment: @Blaisorblade I'm actually not getting a warning about incomplete cases, but about type information getting erased.

Comment: @user unknown thats what I wrote. But you can easily add a case for that

Comment: @Jens Schauder: Ah, I've overseen that. `But you can easily add a case for that.` That's why you didn't? :)

Comment: Interesting, it certainly is a creative solution to the problem :P It's good to see what Scala is and is not capable of.

Comment: @user unknown: Yes, because there a tons of things that are wrong with this code. Not worth bothering to fix one. As Zecrates writes: it shows what is possible. It's not a complete solution for anything and it is not an approach advisable in most normal circumstance.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
def isStraight = {
  cards.map(_.rank).toList match {
    case first :: second :: third :: fourth :: fifth :: Nil if 
      first.id == second.id - 1 &&
      second.id == third.id - 1 &&
      third.id == fourth.id - 1 &&
      fourth.id == fifth.id - 1 => true
    case _ => false
  }
}
```

You're still stuck with the `if` (which is in fact larger) but there's no recursion or custom extractors (which I believe you're using incorrectly with `next` and so is why your second attempt doesn't work).

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing a poker program, you are already check for n-of-a-kind.  A hand is a straight when it has no n-of-a-kinds (n > 1) and the different between the minimum denomination and the maximum is exactly four.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing something like this a few days ago, for Project Euler problem 54. Like you, I had Rank and Suit as enumerations.

My Card class looks like this:

```
  case class Card(rank: Rank.Value, suit: Suit.Value) extends Ordered[Card] {
    def compare(that: Card) = that.rank compare this.rank
  }
```

Note I gave it the `Ordered` trait so that we can easily compare cards later. Also, when parsing the hands, I sorted them from high to low using `sorted`, which makes assessing values much easier.

Here is my `straight` test which returns an `Option` value depending on whether it's a straight or not. The actual return value (a list of Ints) is used to determine the strength of the hand, the first representing the hand type from 0 (no pair) to 9 (straight flush), and the others being the ranks of any other cards in the hand that count towards its value. For straights, we're only worried about the highest ranking card.

Also, note that you can make a straight with Ace as low, the "wheel", or A2345.

```
  case class Hand(cards: Array[Card]) {
    ...
    def straight: Option[List[Int]] = {

      if( cards.sliding(2).forall { case Array(x, y) => (y compare x) == 1 } )
        Some(5 :: cards(0).rank.id :: 0 :: 0 :: 0 :: 0 :: Nil)

      else if ( cards.map(_.rank.id).toList == List(12, 3, 2, 1, 0) )
        Some(5 :: cards(1).rank.id :: 0 :: 0 :: 0 :: 0 :: Nil) 

      else None
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete idiomatic Scala hand classifier for all hands (handles 5-high straights):

```
case class Card(rank: Int, suit: Int) { override def toString = s"${"23456789TJQKA" rank}${"♣♠♦♥" suit}" }

object HandType extends Enumeration {
  val HighCard, OnePair, TwoPair, ThreeOfAKind, Straight, Flush, FullHouse, FourOfAKind, StraightFlush = Value
}

case class Hand(hand: Set[Card]) {
  val (handType, sorted) = {
    def rankMatches(card: Card) = hand count (_.rank == card.rank)
    val groups = hand groupBy rankMatches mapValues {_.toList.sorted}

    val isFlush = (hand groupBy {_.suit}).size == 1
    val isWheel = "A2345" forall {r => hand exists (_.rank == Card.ranks.indexOf(r))}   // A,2,3,4,5 straight
    val isStraight = groups.size == 1 && (hand.max.rank - hand.min.rank) == 4 || isWheel
    val (isThreeOfAKind, isOnePair) = (groups contains 3, groups contains 2)

    val handType = if (isStraight && isFlush)     HandType.StraightFlush
      else if (groups contains 4)                 HandType.FourOfAKind
      else if (isThreeOfAKind && isOnePair)       HandType.FullHouse
      else if (isFlush)                           HandType.Flush
      else if (isStraight)                        HandType.Straight
      else if (isThreeOfAKind)                    HandType.ThreeOfAKind
      else if (isOnePair && groups(2).size == 4)  HandType.TwoPair
      else if (isOnePair)                         HandType.OnePair
      else                                        HandType.HighCard

    val kickers = ((1 until 5) flatMap groups.get).flatten.reverse
    require(hand.size == 5 && kickers.size == 5)
    (handType, if (isWheel) (kickers takeRight 4) :+ kickers.head else kickers)
  }
}

object Hand {
  import scala.math.Ordering.Implicits._
  implicit val rankOrdering = Ordering by {hand: Hand => (hand.handType, hand.sorted)}
}
```